# Elasticbeanstalk; Which is the correct alias target to configure domain name?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to configure custom domanin name on Route 53. 
I'm going to choose Alias target but two official documentation seem different a bit.

[This documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/get-a-domain/) says

> Select the resource you want to point to (this will be under Elastic Load Balancers and should the resource associated with your Elastic Beanstalk deployed application),

and the picture on the doc choose Elastic Load Balancers.

But on the other hand, [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-beanstalk-environment.html#routing-to-beanstalk-environment-get-domain-name) says

> Click in the field, and choose the domain name of the environment that you want to route traffic to. This is the value that you get when you perform the procedure in the topic Getting the Domain Name for Your Elastic Beanstalk Environment.

Also, if I should choose Elastic Load Balancers section, how I can check if the resource's value is associated with app on eb on eb console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alias should be the url of ElasticBeanstalk Environment.
eg- http://something.region.elasticbeanstalk.com

If your ElasticBeansTalk Enviroment is running correctly then its should appear in the suggestions when you click on alias Target input box. Select from there to avoid any typo.
This is working fine for me, selecting to load balancer might work too but I can't be sure as I never tried it.

Comment: what kind of issue?

Comment: Well it's a google auth related problem and since I have never used google auth, sorry I can't help much with that.

Answer (score 1):

The ElasticBeanstalk URL is at the top of the Application Environment page.

To use a custom domain name with ElasticBeanstalk, you should create a CNAME in your DNS (Route53 or other DNS provider) to the subdomain in the ElasticBeanstalk URL.

e.g.
myapp.example.com > *environmentname*.*region*.elasticbeanstalk.com